# Нужно ли очищать консоль?

Tags: python, консоль

Допустим, в консоль идет логирование. Выводятся строки с `print`.

Но не захламляет ли это память, если принтов много и программу держат активной долго? Надо ли очищать консоль? Или вообще убирать все принты? А может это никак не влияет?

Comment: У консолей есть буфер и при новых данных старые будут удаляться

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ответ на этот вопрос зависит от настроек консольного окна (`cmd` в Windows, `terminal` в Linux/MacOS). Обычно параметр, отвечающий за хранения буфера вывода называется `scroll buffer`.

Даже если установить значение этого буфера в 10.000 строк и учесть **среднюю** длину строки в 100 символов, то это займет: `10000 * 100 / 1024 = 977 KiB` - т.е. меньше одного мегабайта.

Поэтому я считаю, что такими мелочами заниматься не стоит.